# How to Load Train and test data from a saved ML model

Tags: machine-learning

I have a saved ML model and I want to load its training and testing set data so that I can add it to the next month data of training and testing

Currently I am  concatnating the x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test of the model to the training and testing se without loading the model

Comment: train/test data is usually not saved to a ML model file, so what you are asking does not make sense or is just impossible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.